# Difficult SQL Query and Subquery For Report

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have bed management module where by a client visits us and we assign a bed to the client. When we assign a bed to a client, the system starts a new episode by adding an entry into the episode table, the system also adds the start date of the visit in the episode table. When the client leaves, then the system adds a new record in the Discharge table and it also adds the end date (the date client leaves). A client may come back and in that case the system starts a second episode in the Episode table and so on....

A client can have multiple episodes and each episode will have 0 or 1 discharge record (depending on whether client is discharged or still occupying a bed).

I need to write a query to receive all those episodes/clients that exist (i.e client occupied a bed) during a specified 12 months period, and the second requirement is out of all the data that fulfilled the first query's requirement, I need to get all those clients/episodes which re-occupied the bed within 6 months of their end date.

I have created a SQL fiddle to make it easier.

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/024f5/1)

If I run this query in/for July 2007 then the start and end date of the 12 month period is 01/01/2006 - 31/12/2006. For Aug 2007, the 12 month period is 01/02/2007 - 31/01/2007 and for Sep 2007, the 12 month period is 01/03/2007 - 28/02/2007. I should receive the following data for each month:

Result:

```
EpisodesOccupyingBed    Didnt Re-Occupied   Re-Occupied
EpisodeID1                                  X
EpisodeID2              X   
EpisodeID3      
Total Jul 07   3        1                      1

EpisodesOccupyingBed    Didnt Re-Occupied   Re-Occupied
EpisodeID4      
EpisodeID2              X   
EpisodeID3      
Total Aug 07  3         1                      0

EpisodesOccupyingBed    Didnt Re-Occupied   Re-Occupied
EpisodeID4      
EpisodeID2              X   
EpisodeID3      
Total Aug 07  3         1                      0
```

Please note that I don't need the output in above format as long as I can receive suitable EpisodeIDs for qualified records.

I am using following query but I don't know how to extract records for re-occupying bed records:

```html
Declare @StartDate DateTime
Declare @EndDate DateTime
Declare @Month varchar(5)
set @Month = 'Jul07' -- set @Month='Aug07' -- set @Month = 'Sep07'
if(@Month = 'Jul07') begin -- report run on July 2007
  set @StartDate = 'January, 01 2006' set @EndDate = 'December, 31 2006'
  end
else if(@Month = 'Aug07')  begin -- report run on July 2007
  set @StartDate = 'February, 01 2006' set @EndDate = 'January, 31 2007'
  end
else if(@Month = 'Sep07') begin
  set @StartDate = 'March, 01 2006' set @EndDate = 'February, 28 2007'
  end
select * from ClientTable as CT inner join EpisodeTable as ET on 
CT.ClientIDCSV = ET.ClientIDCSV
left outer join DischargeTable as DT on 
ET.EpisodeIDCSV=DT.EpisodeIDCSV where
ET.StartDate >= @StartDate and ET.StartDate <= @EndDate
```

Thanks for you help.

Comment: added a new entry in the DischargeTable in SQL Fiddle as I missed out the third row in the DischargeTable

Comment: But you failed to update the Fiddle link.

Comment: @TommCatt I updated the SQL Fiddle and naively thought that the original link points towards the same updated link. Thanks for pointing it out. I have updated the link now with your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to list all the episodes started during the previous year and attach any new episodes for the same clients that started after the first episodes end date. From that it's easy to get the difference in months between the end of the first episode and the start of the next episode and react accordingly.

EDIT: Here's a revised query based on new information.

```
select  e.EpisodeIDCSV,
        case when DateDiff( month,  d.EndDate, e1.StartDate ) > 6 then 'X' end as NoReoccupy,
        case when DateDiff( month,  d.EndDate, e1.StartDate ) <= 6 then 'X' end as Reoccupy
from    Clients c
join    Episodes e
    on  e.ClientIDCSV = c.ClientIDCSV
left join Discharges d
    on  d.EpisodeIDCSV = e.EpisodeIDCSV
join Episodes e1
    on  e1.ClientIDCSV = c.ClientIDCSV
    and e1.StartDate > e.StartDate
left join Discharges d1
    on  d1.EpisodeIDCSV = e1.EpisodeIDCSV
where   e.StartDate >= @StartDate
    and e.StartDate < @EndDate
order by c.EpisodeIDCSV, e.StartDate;
```

Here's SQL Fiddles for [Jul07](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/442e2/2/0), [Aug07](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/442e2/3/0) and [Sep07](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/442e2/4/0). Notice Episode 5 is now showing up in all three time periods as an "intreat" condition. At first I thought it was a problem, but episode 5 starts in all three time periods and is not discharged within any of them. So it qualifies as "in treatment" but you don't show it in any of your examples. On what basis do you disqualify it?

Comment: It does return correct rows for July07. But it doesn't return EpisodeID4 for Aug07 & Sep07. Please note that EpisodeID4 needs to be returned in the 'InTreat' column because the client/EpisodeID4 was occupying the bed during that time. I have added another case statement in your query but of no use.

Comment: It makes it that much more difficult when you present us with a moving target such as adding a new column to the desired output.

Here's another question: why wouldn't EpisodeID3 appear as a Reoccupy for all three time periods? It started during all three periods and though it didn't end until 2008, that client reoccupied 2 months later.

Comment: The EpisodeID3 wouldn't appear in July07, Aug07 & Sep07 because a client has to left inside a reporting period to qualify for reoccupy or noreoccupy. The EpisodeID3 would appear as a Reoccupy for Aug08 report. Sorry about extra column, you could ignore that as long as the relevant EpisodeID appears in the EpisodesOccupyingBed field which was in the original question. I added InTreat to denote EpisodesOccupyingBed column to clarify things because it was not included in your query.

Comment: So the the admission *and* the discharge must be in the reporting period?

Comment: Further explanation: Yes that is correct, admission and the discharge must be in the reporting period to qualify for either 'ReOccupy' or 'NoReoccupy'. But if client was occupying the bed during a reporting period and was not discharged during the reporting period then the episodeid must show in EpisodesOccupyingBed.